# How do i tell the typesafe activator to serve play applications over https?

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

I believe that the play framework can self sign a certificate and serve applications over https if asked to - is this also doable with the typesafe activator? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today this can't be done from the Activator UI but it is something that we are working on.  In the meantime you can do this from the `activator` CLI.  More info: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ConfiguringHttps

Comment: https://www.stunnel.org/index.html is an alternative workaround, which might fit some dev setups.